# Split power supply for a multiple op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

[image]I'm working on a 9V VCO (synthesiser) that has three op amps, of which two needs virtual ground. So far I've been using voltage divider with a couple of caps and it works. I wonder if I need a separate power supply for each op amp? Is the TLE2426 any better? Do I need two of the TLE2426 for the two op amps?

Comment: The LM324N has input and output ranges going to the negative rail but being 1.5V shy of the positive rail.  So it makes sense to put your virtual ground closer to the negative rail for best headroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have no issues running multiple amplifiers from the same virtual ground.  However, the virtual ground circuit itself will depend on what your circuit is doing.  If you will be driving DC levels, you can't use a simple voltage divider without any buffering, for example.  This is a good page that gives an overview of virtual ground techniques:

http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html

Answer (score 3):

Using a voltage divider with a decent capacitor to 0v usually does the trick for several op amps but you can bolster the mid rail up with a dedicated op amp as a unity gain buffer.

Comment: Excellent! What resistor value should I use for the voltage divider?

Comment: 10k ohm is a sort of standard default value but  if running from a battery 100k might be considered. A circuit might help spot any pitfalls. Is it a linear vco or log vco?

Comment: Logarithmic but the CV stage has an antilog amp.

Comment: @alkopop79 I wouldn't mind taking a look at the circuit design so if you get a chance please do post it.

Comment: @alkopop79 I'm not recognizing the log part of the vco - i can see that T1's collector discharges cap C1 but won't this be at a rate dependent on i/p voltage not log(i/p)? I's nothing to do with your question of course!

Comment: The 40106 and the cap forms an oscillator. The transistor turns linear voltage change into non-linear one.

Comment: I've seen your latest question and I hope there is a good answer - I'm genuinely unsure but if you have it working as a log amp i.e. x volts per octave then coolio.